# Laravel Livewire component disappears on typing

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

**The problem**

I am trying to make a dynamic app sidebar to react and refresh when a new content category is created. However **emitTo('docs.sidebar', 'refresh')** to *'docs.sidebar'* component is not working.

I have found out that when i start typing into input field - component ***'docs.sidebar'*** disappears from loaded components in debugbar. Which obviously means that something refreshed in whole layout and the only component remains is the 'docs.create-category'.

Component 'docs.sidebar' has ***$listener*** for refresh included and is included in main layout using livewire directive.

```php
@livewire('docs.sidebar')
```

And the component 'docs.create-category' is a full page component using the main layout where 'docs.sidebar' is included.

**What have i tried?**

I have tried to add *wire:ignore* and *wire:ignore.self* in both correlating components various places, however that did no help.

Attaching screen recording to see problem visually.

https://youtu.be/kkOrgQXVyGo

Views:
Layout: https://paste.laravel.io/7dfe2b11-e7c9-4905-a644-133c783e8ba6

Create category component: https://paste.laravel.io/92ea800a-96bc-4286-aedc-f16a65aa4e3f

Comment: What does your relevant views look like? `wire:ignore` is probably not relevant here and should not be used

Comment: What does the `docs.sidebar` look like?